# Find & Replace text from multiple specific files from sub folders dynamically using powershell

Tags: powershell, subdirectory, azure-powershell, file-access

I am working on azure CD pipeline, i want to change content of multiple files which exist in following folder structure.

```
MainFolder => SubFolder1 => myFile1.txt
              SubFolder2 => myFile2.txt
              SubFolder3 => myFile3.txt
```

I want to achieve my above requirement using powershell, and i have tried the following code.

```
$filepath = 'C:\Users\ashishjain06\Desktop\MainFolder'
$mydata = Get-ChildItem $filepath -include *.txt -recurse | Select-Object fullName
$totalRecords = $mydata.Count
for($x = 0; $x -lt $totalRecords; $x++)
{
    ((Get-Content -path $mydata[$x] -Force) -replace 'oldText','newText') | Set-Content -Path $mydata[$x]
}
```

When i run above code it's give me following output.

```
Get-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{FullName=C' does not exist.
At line:6 char:7
+     ((Get-Content -path $mydata[$x] -Force) -replace 'oldText ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (@{FullName=C:String) [Get-Content], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:6 char:25
+     ((Get-Content -path $mydata[$x] -Force) -replace 'oldText ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:6 char:25
+     ((Get-Content -path $mydata[$x] -Force) -replace 'oldText ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:6 char:25
+     ((Get-Content -path $mydata[$x] -Force) -replace 'oldText ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:6 char:25
+     ((Get-Content -path $mydata[$x] -Force) -replace 'oldText ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

I am newbie on powershell, Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still an object with a property unless you do this:

```
select-object -expandproperty fullname
```

Comment: Thanks a lot js2010, it's working like a charm, LotPings also given same sugessions but you just picked the broken nerve. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 3):

[Get-ChildIItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1) returns (an array of) `FileInfoObjects` with a bunch of properties,
[Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/select-object?view=powershell-5.1) drops all but the selected one, but it is still an object with one property `FullName`.
See `$mydata | Get-Member`

One method is `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`,
another one is the [property dereference operator .](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1) used in the following script.

To have the script work on any user don't include a fixed path, either use  `$Env:USERPROFILE` or better yet, let the system evaluate current users Desktop folder (which might be relocated).

Instead of iterating the arrray `$mydata` by index let powershell do that with a `foreach`:

```
$filepath = Join-Path ([environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')) 'MainFolder'
$files = (Get-ChildItem $filepath -Filter *.txt -Recurse).FullName

foreach($file in $files){
   (Get-Content -path $file -Force) -replace 'oldText','newText' | Set-Content -Path $file
}
```

Comment: Dear LotPings, i will try this one but as i go through this, you are right. I have accepted js2010 as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Select-Object` with `ForEach-Object`, i.e.:

```
$filepath = 'C:\Users\ashishjain06\Desktop\MainFolder'
#$mydata = Get-ChildItem $filepath -include *.txt -recurse | Select-Object fullName
$mydata = Get-ChildItem $filepath -include *.txt -recurse | ForEach-Object fullName
$totalRecords = $mydata.Count
for($x = 0; $x -lt $totalRecords; $x++)
{
    ((Get-Content -path $mydata[$x] -Force) -replace 'oldText','newText') | Set-Content -Path $mydata[$x]
}
```